# ARP cache: what does a `mask` value of `*` represent?

Tags: linux, networking, arp

`/proc/net/arp` contains something like the following on my Linux box:

```
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
10.1.0.70      0x1         0x2         a4:4d:aa:6b:f7:1a     *        eno1
10.1.0.1       0x1         0x2         bc:8f:aa:fb:aa:11     *        eno1
```

I've searched the manual (`man arp`) looked at the [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc826.html) and did some web searches but can't find out what `*` means in the `Mask` column. Does this mean `255.255.255.255`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed the netmask for that cache entry – but only used for "published" (i.e. "proxy ARP") entries where the kernel would respond on behalf of some other machine. You can find mentions of it in the [arp(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/arp.8.html) manual page for the `arp` command. Normal (non-published) cache entries didn't have a mask and always listed `*`.

This functionality was removed in Linux 2.1.79. Since then, the column always says `*` and any attempts to create a proxy-ARP entry with a netmask different from 255.255.255.255 are rejected.

(Note that many of the network-related /proc interfaces are somewhat outdated and might be missing information. Current tools, such as `ip neighbor` (`ip n`), use the Netlink interface instead of /proc to retrieve the neighbour cache.)